# Is there any situation where document.URL could be blank?

Tags: dom, webapi

I'm seeing a lot of traffic where document.URL (and document.referer) are blank. This seems suspicious to me. Are there any valid reasons document.URL could be blank?

Thanks

Comment: Privacy-focused web-browsers and privacy-enhancing browser extensions will blank-out the `document.referer`, so that's not unusual.

Comment: There is no property named `document.url` - [it's named `document.URL` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL) - what happens if you use that property instead?

Comment: @Dai yes I meant document.URL, just a typo here at stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, **how** are you detecting that `document.URL` is blank?

Comment: I'm just reading the document.URL value and seeing if it exists or is blank. It usually gives an expected response, but I'm noticing sometimes it's blank.

Comment: How are you checking if it's "blank" though? What `readyState`s are you checking it in? What happens if you wait until the DOM `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` events?

Comment: I'm checking it after the DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: According to [this Chromium issue from 2015-2017](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=563986) _it simply shouldn't be possible_ for `document.URL` to be an empty string - it should be `"about:blank"` otherwise. Do you have any more information about the cases where your script detects it is blank, such as any commonalities like the same web-browser being used?

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. We suspect the traffic is bot traffic. We got a huge burst of it all at once.